# Combinatorical explanation for $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}(n!)}$ being the number of ways to split $2n$ objects into groups of $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, intuition

I am wondering whether there is a simple way to understand why $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}n!}$ is equal to the number of ways to split $2n$ objects into groups of $2$? I get exercise questions involving this formula but I want to know why this formula is used. :)

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $(2n)!$ in the numerator?

Comment: And shouldn't it be "$n$ pairs" not "$2$ groups"?

Comment: This [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1388608/111334) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we already have a grouping of $2n$ objects into pairs. We could write this down as a big list of $2n$ objects, where the first and second items in the list form a pair, the third and fourth are a pair, and so on. However, we have a lot of redundancy in this list, meaning that the *same* grouping could be written out as many *different* lists:

- For each pair of objects $\{A, B\}$, we could write $A$ onto the list followed by $B$, or $B$ onto the list followed by $A$. So for each pair we have, we get a factor of $2$ to the number of lists we could write.
- The pairs themselves don't come with an ordering, so we could reorder the pairs and write down a different list, which would mean the same grouping of objects into pairs. There are $n!$ ways to rearrange the pairs on the list.

The two facts above mean that a single grouping of objects into pairs could be written in $2^n n!$ different ways as a list of $2n$ objects. There are $(2n)!$ possible lists of $2n$ objects, and so we get the formula.

Comment: Phrased in the language of group theory, by associating a splitting with a list, we have a transitive action on the collection of splittings by the symmetric group $S_{2n}$.  However, every splitting has a stabilizer group given by $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n \times S_n$, and thus the total number of splittings is the size of the orbits, which by the orbit-stabilizer theorem is the size of the group divided by the size of the orbit.  Thinking about enumeration problems in terms of symmetries is useful, and enables more interesting methods like Polya enumeration.