# Number of unique pairings of k values.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

So to make this clear, this is not just n choose 2.
what im talking about is related to this: [Combination of splitting elements into pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35684/combination-of-splitting-elements-into-pairs)
but also all pairs less than 6.

so basically for 3 values 1,2,3 you have 3 pairings:
$${(1,2),3}, $$
$${(2,3),1},$$
$${(1,3),2}$$
for 4 values you have
all single pairs and 2 left over:

$${(1,2),3,4},$$
$${(1,3),2,4},$$
$${(1,4),2,3},$$
$${(2,3),1,4},$$
$${(2,4),1,3},$$
$${(3,4),1,2}$$
all double pairings:
$${(1,2),(3,4)},$$
$${(1,3),(2,4)},$$
$${(1,4),(2,3)}$$

so a total of 6+3 = 9 pairings.

for 5 there is:
1 pair,3 left over and
2 pairs, 1 leftover
and so on.

I'm wondering if there is a closed formula for this and I am looking for the value of 13.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: What does "all pairs less than $6$" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a formula (although maybe not very closed-form, you would definitely want a computer to do this for you) via that logic. First with one pairing, you have $n \choose 2$ possibilities. For 2 pairs, you have ${n\choose2} {n-2\choose 2}$, but notice that this has an order given to the two pairs, so we divide by 2!. For 3 pairs, you get $\frac1{3!}{n\choose2}{n-2\choose2}{n-4\choose2}$, and so on. So, you can write the answer as a sum.

From a quick calculation, you can find the values here: https://oeis.org/A001189
So for 13, there are 568503 pairings.